# Which value should I take for the temperature of a cabinet with electronic devices in order to find the maximum power?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, power, thermal-conductivity

I have a cabinet with electronic stuff, I need to calculate Watt at critical conditions.
inside the cabinet I have a temperature ranging from 18 to 28 celsius degree.
electronic stuff are designed to work without problems even if their temperature ranges from 35 to 55 celsius degree. (so they could have a temperature from 0°C to 55°C, but 35°C to 55°C is the critical range)

I've calculated total resistance of walls and it's equal to: $0.0421 °C/W$
now I have to use this equation: $Q_{max} = \frac{\delta T}{R_{tot}}$
(Q is Watt).

my question is: in order to calculate Q_max at critical conditions, which criteria should I use to determine which temperatures I have to use? in the cabinet it's easy, because I just take the maximum value of this range $T_1 = max[18, 28] = 28 °C$, but I don't know how to choose the right value for the electronic devices.

solution of the exercise takes the minimum of the critical range but why should I use the minimum?

Comment: If your requirement is that the inside of the cabinet never exceeds 55 degrees C and that the outside is always guaranteed to be below 28 degrees C, then the max. temperature difference you are allowed is given by these two extremes. I would warn you about the assumption that electronics will work "without problems" at 55 degrees C. The lifetime of certain components (like cheap electrolytic capacitors) will be greatly reduced because the temperature inside of these parts is significantly higher than on the outside. That's also true for semiconductors and power resistors.